# Erro: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, lista

Em uma competição de salto em distância cada atleta tem direito a cinco saltos.
O resultado do atleta será determinado pela média dos cinco valores restantes.
Você deve fazer um programa que receba o nome e as cinco distâncias alcançadas pelo atleta em seus saltos e depois informe o nome,
os saltos e a média dos saltos. O programa deve ser encerrado quando não for informado o nome do atleta.

Está dando erro nesta linha

```
print(nsaltos[j],todosaltos[i[j]]," m")
```

> builtins.TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
nsaltos = ['Primeiro Salto: ','Segundo Salto: ','Terceiro Salto: 
','Quarto Salto: ','Quinto Salto: ']
atletas = []
saltos = []
todosaltos = []
nome = 0
media = 0
lstsalto = ""
while True:
    nome = str(input("Digite o nome: "))
    atletas.append(nome)
    if nome == '':
       break
    for i in range(5):
        distancia = float(input("Digite a distancia %d: "%(i+1)))
        saltos.append(distancia)
    todosaltos.append(saltos)
    saltos = []
atletas.pop(len(atletas)-1)
for i in range(len(atletas)):
    print("Atleta: ",atletas[i])
    print("")
    for j in range(len(todosaltos[i])):
        print(nsaltos[j],todosaltos[i[j]]," m")
        media += todosaltos[i[j]]
        convsalto = str(todosaltos[i[j]])+" -"
        lstsalto += convsalto
    print("Resultado final:")
    print("Atleta: ",atletas[i])
    print("Saltos: ",lstsalto)
    print("Média dos saltos: ",(media/5)," m")
    media = 0
    lstsalto = ""
```

Comment: Você está tentando acessar a posição `j` de um número inteiro `i` quando faz `[i[j]]`. Acredito que o que você pretendia fazer é `[i][j]`, utilizando colchetes separados. Fora isso, acredito que é possível melhorar bastante o código.

Comment: Novamente pergunto erro bobo aqui, juro que pesquiso antes de perguntar, mas n achei nd. Como poderia melhorar o código? sou burro em programação

Answer (score 1):

Como comentei, o erro é dado nesta linha porquê você fez: `[i[j]]`. Com este código, você está acessando a posição `j` da variável `i`; como `i` é uma variável do tipo `int`, não é possível fazer isso, gerando o erro. Acredito que o desejado era fazer `[i][j]`, para assim acessar a posição `j` do valor na posição `i`.

Com essa alteração seu código parece funcionar como desejado.

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Kv6x).

Porém, acredito que o código pode ser melhorado. Motivo esse de eu responder e não só votar para fechar a pergunta como erro de digitação. Seu código possui muitos vícios que são comuns de pessoas que começam no Python já sabendo outra linguagem - geralmente C. Isso fica muito claro quando você usa o `range(len(...))`. Seu código é funcional, mas não idiomático, isto é, não utiliza as devidas ferramentas que a linguagem oferece para resolver o problema.

Primeiro, eu não armazenaria o nome e os valores das distâncias em listas separadas. São dados diretamente relacionados entre si e faz sentido você armazená-los juntos. Eu utilizaria um dicionário com as chaves `nome` e `saltos` para armazenar as informações e armazenaria esse dicionário em uma lista. Algo como:

```
atletas = []

while True:

    nome = input("Nome?")

    if not nome: break

    saltos = []
    for i in range(5):
        salto = float(input("Distância {}?".format(i+1)))
        saltos.append(salto)

    atletas.append({
        "nome": nome,
        "saltos": saltos
    })

for atleta in atletas:
    print("Nome:", atleta["nome"])
    print("Saltos:", atleta["saltos"])
    print("Média:", sum(atleta["saltos"])/5)
```

Perceba que o cálculo da média fica muito mais simples se você utilizar `sum(...)/5`. Ao ler o nome, você não precisa converter para *string*, pois o retorno de `input` sempre será deste tipo já. Aliás, o programa não fala sobre a necessidade de armazenar esses valores em uma lista, então a exibição do nome e média poderia ser feita no mesmo laço que a leitura, não precisando criar a lista `atletas`.

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Kva6/0).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, ainda n conheço dicionários nem essa função sum(), mas aprenderei e passarei a utilizar nos meu futuros códigos. Mt obrigado mesmo, aprendi mt com vc.

Comment: kkkkk e sim eu comecei com C